# Increase number recently opened file list in gedit (gnome)

Tags: gnome, gedit

I have been using gedit as a programming text editor for a while...

I would like to increase the number of recently opened files from 5 to 10...

I checked the gedit preferences and the gconf-editor gedit options but there was nothing there related to the recently opened file list.

Where can I change this setting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The configuration setting is in `/schemas/apps/gedit-2/preferences/ui/recents/max_recents` according to http://people.gnome.org/~bmsmith/gconf-docs/C/gedit.html.

According to OP the setting can successfully be changed by issuing the command `gconftool-2 --type int --set /apps/gedit-2/preferences/ui/recents/max_recents 10` (Notice: `/schemas` is removed!)

Comment: Thanks for the super-quick response I just tried to edit the schemas from gconf-editor but got an error message: "Currently pairs and schemas can't be edited. This will be chagned in a later version"... when editing with the comand line: "gconftool-2 --type int --set /schemas/apps/gedit-2/preferences/ui/recents/max_recents 10" the value seems to have changed in the gconf-editor, but the change are not reflected in gedit... I will have to investigate further. Thanks again for your response!

Comment: @ischnura Hmm, I'm not really sure whether the config needs to be reloaded. A quick search turned up this: `gconftool-2 --shutdown && gconftool-2 --spawn`

Comment: playing with gconf-editor I found that changing the /apps/gedit-2/preferences/ui/recents/max_recents instead of /schemas/apps/gedit-2/preferences/ui/recents/max_recents made it work! Thanks for your response!

Comment: @ischnura Great! I will write this into the answer in order to let other people find it.

Comment: Seems to be broken in gnome 3.x (at least 3.8) :-(

Answer (score 3):

I tried the accepted answer with Ubuntu 14.04 and as pevik ran into the problem that adding that did not do anything.

Instead, I had to change the already existing key in dconf:

```
$ dconf write /org/gnome/gedit/preferences/ui/max-recents '20'
```

EDIT: Since after a restart gEdit's number of most recently used items was reduced to 5 again, I did some investigation and found [bug #1024168 on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/d-conf/+bug/1024168) and it seems that the solution is not using `dconf` at all, but instead `gsettings`:

```
$ dconf read /org/gnome/gedit/preferences/ui/max-recents
20
$ gsettings get org.gnome.gedit.preferences.ui max-recents
uint32 5
$ gsettings set org.gnome.gedit.preferences.ui max-recents 25
$ dconf read /org/gnome/gedit/preferences/ui/max-recents
25
$ gsettings get org.gnome.gedit.preferences.ui max-recents
uint32 25
```

So, it seems that the information flow dconf -> gsettings does not work properly, while gsettings -> dconf works as expected. On a side-note: dconf claims the key to be a signed int32, while gsettings states that it is an unsigned int32...

Comment: In recent versions of `gedit` though (I have 3.36.2), `max-recents` seems not to be available through either `dconf` or `gsettings`